# jquery :gt selector bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Did anybody faced any problems with gt selector? I'm using jQuery (version 1.11.0) in a phonegap app so please do not ask to post the whole code, because it will be huge. Anyway I have the next problem, I have some divs which are added and occasionally removed dynamically, now I know very well that `:gt` is 0 based selector, but still if I'm try to use :`gt(1)` it does not want to work, here is a small piece of code:

```
alert($(".sima").length+"------"+ ($(this).parents(".sima").index()-1));
$(".sima:gt("+($(this).parents(".sima").index()-1)+")").remove();
```

my alert will return 2 ----- 1, meaning totally there are 2 elements with class .sima, and currently I'm trying to remove all those which are greater than 2 so, nothing removed. So far so good, but this happens if the alert returns: 3 ------ 1 as well, 4 ------ 1 and so on.

On all other scenarios everything is working fine, so when I have 4 ----- 2 all the elements matching the class .sima greater then 2 will be removed as I expect, it's just does not want to work when it's `:gt(1)`

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example at jsfiddle?

Comment: I will try to, it will take a bit of time, since all of this is populated from server, based on lot's of parameters.

Comment: What happens when you try jQuery v1.10?

Comment: A fiddle need not be complex: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/WKu7q Seems to work fine.

Comment: isherwood -  Same with V1.10 I know what, and I know what you mean with an simple jsfiddle, but I need to reproduce the error, not to have a working example.

Comment: You specifically asked whether anyone had problems with the selector. The fiddle addresses that. As to the larger question of your code--looks like James has provided a likely solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that clicking on the first element isn't giving you `1` it is giving you `-1`.  However, you have used `----` as your separator so it's blending.